# Get String token value in flex and bison more than it is intended

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I tried to get the value of the token in bison, but it seems that I get more than one token at once.
Here is my flex code:

```
    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"
    //YYSTYPE yylval;
    %}
    semicolon   [;]
    var [a-c]
    digit   [0-9]+
    string [a-zA-Z]+
    %%
    Counter {yylval = yytext; return VAR;}
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+ { yylval = yytext; return STRING;}
    ....
```

Here is my bison code :

```
    %{
    #define YYSTYPE char *
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int limit;
    int input;
    int count=0;
    char a[20];
    char message[200];
    %}
    %token DIGIT VAR OPENPAR CLOSEPAR PETIK
    %token WRITELN DO FOR BEGINKEY END TO EQUAL
    %token SEMICOLON VARKEY COLON TYPE STRING READLN
    %start program
    %%

    program: dlist slist {printf("L3: HALT");}
      ;

    dlist:  /* nothing */
      | decl dlist 
      ;

    decl:   VARKEY VAR COLON TYPE SEMICOLON 
      ;

    slist:  stmt 
      | stmt slist
      | BEGINKEY FOR VAR EQUAL DIGIT TO DIGIT DO slist END 
        { 
          printf("\nBeginFunc\n");
          printf("t%d = %d;\n",count,$5);
          printf("%s = t%d\n",$3,count); 

      ....
```

So the problem is when I input writeln('forloop');. The program should only get the forloop, but it get forloop');
But when I input line by line like this :
forloop
'
)
;
It shows only forloop
What may cause this problem?

Comment: Be careful of tagging; the Flex tag is used for the Adobe/Apache UI framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to process or duplicate `yytext` before you pass it to `bison`. `bison` will request look ahead tokens from the scanner and those will overwrite any `yytext`.

For identifiers typically `strdup` or an ANSI-C equivalent is used. If the language has only one namespace or the namespaces can be distinguished in the scanner already, then it is customary to build the symbol table(s) in the scanner directly and pass a number of the identifier only.

For numbers typically the value of the number is determined and passed to the parser.

Some of the terms above may be unfamiliar to you, but it will be worthwhile for you to investigate what they mean.

Comment: Is there any idea on how to do it? Because I got no idea

Answer (score -1):

This is really an FAQ, and seeing it asked and asked again lets me wonder why this kind of question is not flagged as duplicate.  Even Bison has an FAQ about it.  http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Strings-are-Destroyed.html